# How can I do to adjust the button size with the text size on kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making an app on kivy and in I need to build a text that ever single word is a button, so I need to adjust the button size with the word size without any border. How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
size_hint: None, None
size: self.texture_size
```